# Create array of IplImage ponters (IplImage**) from EmguCV using C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want create array of IplImage pointers from C#.
I know way to create IplImage pointer.

```
IntPtr imgPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(StructSize.MIplImage);
```

But I want to create array of it.
I tried something like this.

```
IntPtr[] imgArrayPointers = new IntPtr[100];
```

But in I need the size of array not be initialized at the beginning.
Like this in OpenCV.

```
IplImage ** ArrayOfPonters = 0;
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Sachira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep an array un-allocated you just have to declare it like that :

`IntPtr[] imgArrayPointers = null;`

And then, when you need space, you eventually do :

`imgArrayPointers = new IntPtr[100];`